# Automatically locating a file

Tags: vba

By default AutoCAD installs a text based file called acad2010.lsp at the set location below

```
Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Program Files\AutoCAD 2010\Support\acad2010.lsp"
```

However it my be that the user/ administrator/ or third party has changed the location of this file.  Is it possible to then locate it using the following

```
Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\*\acad2010.lsp"
```

In other words search the entire c:\ drive for file acad2010.lsp?

If this doesn't work can you please let me know what would?

Answer (score 3):

You could search for it with an FSO. It's not going to be fast however you do it but this is the fastest way I can think of.

http://www.microbion.co.uk/developers/fso.htm should give you a rough idea of how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution will not work. **Is not possible to locate it using ***. (BTW is possible in ms-builds scripts). The only way of doing it is:

> ```
> 1- Create a FindFile function (check for example
> ```
>
> http://xlvba.3.forumer.com/index.php?showtopic=125)
>
> ```
> 2- Use it to locate the exact path of the file. (It could be really time
> ```
>
> consuming)
>
> ```
> 3- From this point your code is the same...
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't use wildcards in a filepath.  You have two options:

1. Prompt the user for the file location using the "Open File" dialog.  The code to do this varies based on which Office product you are using.  In Excel, you would use the `Application.FindFile` method (more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195731%28office.11%29.aspx)).
2. Write your own function to search the filesystem for the file.  Microsoft provides an example [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185476).

Comment: Application.FindFile is part of the MS Excel library.  It is not a part of VBA itself.  The OP may be using Excel, but he doesn't say that.

Comment: @mwolfe02: Thanks for pointing that out.  Each Office app has a way to show the file open dialog but apparently it's not always the same.  I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If that file is used by internal functions of the application,  the installer will have recorded a registry key for the file's location.

Open regedit.exe and search for the file name and path.

You can read a registry entry using this VBA one-liner:

`CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegRead(strRegPath)`

You may need a terminating backslash on the key address, but that's a safe and simple registry access method. More details on the MSDN site:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x05fawxd%28v=vs.84%29.aspx